# Trouble converting string to date format in amazon athena

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, presto, trino

I have a CSV file that I have uploaded onto amazon s3 and loaded as a table into Amazon Athena. The CSV file has a string column which contains date values in the following format: YYYYMMDD. For example, January 1, 2012 would be 20120101. I am trying to convert this column into a date column in athena so I can run temporal queries, but nothing seems to be working. Is there a convenient way to achieve this task?

I tried using several sql functions like `parse_datetime` and `date_parse` but this did not work.

Answer (score 0):

TBH not sure what  the actual problem is but both of the mentioned function require correct format to be passed. For example for [`date_parse`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html):

```sql
-- sample data
with dataset(dt) as (
    values ('20120101'),
           ('20211231')
)

-- query
SELECT date_parse(dt, '%Y%m%d')
FROM dataset;
```

Output:

| _col0 |
| --- |
| 2012-01-01 00:00:00.000 |
| 2021-12-31 00:00:00.000 |

If this does not work for some values you can wrap the parse in [`try`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/conditional.html#try) which will return `null` if conversion fails.